# How to get list of protocol mappings for WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wcf

I was wondering if anyone knows how to get a list of protocol mappings for WCF (kind of similar to what the ***ServiceHost.AddDefaultEndpoints*** function does for itself) regardless of where the mappings come from (machine.config, app.config, web.config, etc..)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I'm sharing it here for others:

```
Dim pms As ProtocolMappingSection = CType(ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/protocolMapping"), ProtocolMappingSection)
Dim pmc As ProtocolMappingElementCollection = pms.ProtocolMappingCollection

For Each pme As ProtocolMappingElement In pmc
    If String.Compare(pme.Scheme, uri.Scheme, True) = 0 Then
        ' Do something
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```